# How to use factory_girl to build parent model within child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have this setup:

```
  factory :agency do |a|
    a.agents_attributes { [FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:agent)] }
    a.subdomain 'clear'
    a.name 'ClearProperty'
  end

  factory :agent do |a|
    agency
    a.email 'user@test.com'
    a.password 'please'
  end
```

Agency has_many Agents and an agency must be present.  How to resolve this chicken-n-egg?  I want to do Factory(:agent) but this will call Factory(:agency) which will then attempt build another agent.

Comment: why don't you create a declination of your `agency` factory, which wouldn't create any `agent`.

Comment: @apneadiving The biz logic is such that an Agency is not valid without an Agent, but for factories I could certainly do that. If no better solution arrives, that's the one I'll take.

Comment: @apneadiving On second thought, I don't think that will work. Agency validates presence of one set of agent_attributes.

Comment: rereading your question, I can't see any real problem. You can define associated objects easily. Have a look here: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/254496652/aint-no-calla-back-girl . So you could simply pass the created agent to the agency.

Comment: did you notice the factory girl episode has been updated in Railscasts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
  factory :agency do |a|
    a.agents_attributes { [FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:agent)] }
    a.subdomain 'clear'
    a.name 'ClearProperty'
  end

  factory :agent do |a|
    a.email 'user@test.com'
    a.password 'please'
    a.after_create { |a| FactoryGirl.create(:agency, agent_ids: [a.id], agents_attributes: {}) }
  end
```